# how to use flurl to get the response body with query string parameters

Tags: flurl

how to use flurl to get the response body with query string parameters. I tried using Postman and the results were as I expected. but I can't apply it to flurl.

```
var strUrl = await  "https://example.com/api/v2/xxx/yyy?need_personalize=true&promotionid=2007354722&sort_soldout=true"
            .WithHeaders(new
            {
                user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
                content_type = "application/json",
                referer = "https://example.com/xxx",
                cookie = myCookies

            })

            .PostJsonAsync(new
            {
                need_personalize = true,
                promotionid = 2007354722,
                sort_soldout = true
            });

        bodyUrl = await strUrl.GetStringAsync();
```

the results I got : 200

```
{
  "version": "6f1e0da21b667876ba3853b59a8bb812",
  "error_msg": null,
  "error": 10010
}
```

the resulting response should be like this :

```
{
  "version": "6f1e0da21b667876ba3853b59a8bb812",
  "data": {
    "selling_out_item_brief_list": [
      {
        "itemid": 466536326,
        "from": null
      }
    ],
    "items": [],
    "mega_sale_items": [],
    "item_brief_list": [
      {
        "itemid": 6720842242,
        "from": null,
        "is_soldout": false
      }
    ],
    "promotionid": 2007354722
  },
  "error_msg": null,
  "error": 0
}
```

maybe anyone can help me?

Comment: Apparently, communication with your server is working, so this is not FlUrl issue. So I would look into server API documentation and look for 10010 error.